# extract raster value interactively in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, data-capture

How to extract (interpolated) raster values interactively ? i.e. using the mouse to click on a specific map location (lat/long) and get the value from the selected raster.

Comment: Check identify features tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the identify tool. It will return the raster value at every clicked location.
[image]